# Bernoulli trial on Poisson random variable

Tags: binomial-distribution, poisson-distribution

I am trying to assess the sensitivity of an electronic system under alpha radiation.

In "dynamic" mode, the system performs different kinds of operations (without any pause) which might fail due to radiation. If a failure is detected, the system is "rebooted" automatically. I have observed that the times to failure follow an exponential distribution (as is usually the case). Thus, I could derive a sensitivity of the system (i.e. a FIT)

In "standby" mode, assessing the sensitivity is trickier (the test algorithm is 3rd-party and not very tunable). I can only set the duration of a standby phase (which lasts 0s in dynamic mode).

I have decided to set a standby duration $T$, irradiate within this duration for a time $t$ ($t<T$), and observe whether the system is failing after the standby phase (i.e. when it resumes its operations).

I make the assumption that the "potential" number of errors that are due to the irradiation during standby follows a Poisson law. However, I can only observe these errors as one single failure when resuming from standby.
The probability of system "failure" is the probability of having one or more "potential" errors during this standby phase; using the Poisson pmf, it is $p=1-e^{-\lambda}$.

Now to estimate $p$, I repeat this experiment a respectable number of times (50). These 50 experiments are deemed independent since the system is reset now matter what the outcome (failure/no failure) after the standby phase. $p$ is estimated as the fraction of "system failures" out of the 50 experiments. I am using the R `binom` package to have a confidence interval for $p$.

The irradiation duration during standby phase has been kept reasonable in order to avoid stacking "potential" errors; in practice, I should observe a modest number of system failures out of the 50 experiments (which I did, after tuning of the irradiation duration). Ideally, I would like the system failures to be only due to one "potential" error.

Questions:

1. Is it right to safely derive from $p$ the $\lambda$ parameter of the Poisson law ruling the sensitivity of the system in standby mode, with $\lambda=-ln(1-p)$? And is it right to apply the former formula to the bounds of the confidence interval of $p$ to have a confidence interval for $\lambda$?
2. Is there a criterion to be sure -- with a given confidence --, that the system failure obtained after the standby phase is only due to one "potential" error obtained during the standby phase?

Comment: I'm not sure what your second question means; do you mean that any one error is guaranteed to cause a system failure?

Comment: Exactly; one or more errors cumulated in the standby phase (referred to as "potential" errors in the question) give birth to a system failure. It is not good to cumulate errors in the standby phase, because we eventually only observe one system failure -- and we would like it to be due to only ONE "potential" error.